# Assign String Values to Buttons - JavaFx

Tags: java, string, javafx

Im trying to set up a tic tac toe game, and I have created 9 string values for each  button.  Once the button is pressed it assignes a string value to it depending on if it is an X or O.  At the end I concatenated all the strings to output a winning message to the consol but it doesnt seem to work.

Code for a button

```
            // Create a Button
    Button TopLeft = new Button("");
    root.getChildren().add(TopLeft);
    // Move the Button
    TopLeft.setTranslateX(-150);
    TopLeft.setTranslateY(-150);
    // Action for the Button
    // Code from: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm
    TopLeft.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            if (playerX == true) {
                TopLeft.setText("X");
                 tl = "X";

            } else {
                TopLeft.setText("O");
                 tl = "O";

            }

            playerX = !playerX;
            TopLeft.setDisable(true);
        }

    });
```

Win Condition

```
//WIN CONDITION, r1 = row 1, c1 = column 1, d1 = diagonal 1, etc        
     r1 = tl + tm + tr;
     r2 = l + m + r;
     r3 = bl + bm + br;
     c1 = tl + l + bl;
     c2 = tm + m + bm;
     c3 = tr + r + br;
     d1 = tl + m + br;
     d2 = tr + m + bl;


    if((r1.equals("XXX") || r2.equals("XXX") || r3.equals("XXX") || c1.equals("XXX") || c2.equals("XXX") || c3.equals("XXX") || d1.equals("XXX") || d2.equals("XXX")) == true){
        System.out.println("Player X Wins");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Player O Wins");
    }
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Are your buttons not changing their label text, or is your program failing to find winning conditions?

Comment: The question is not clear. Please post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Add an action command like this to your button which is referenced:

```
    TopLeft.setActionCommand("ButtonX");
```

In your handle method

```
    String action = e.getActionCommand();

    if (action.equals("ButtonX") {
           // code here
    }
```

Comment: Because  @Selim doesn't know how to get a value in an active event.

Comment: Why does he need to? What does your code do that his doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if a player won immediately after the button has been clicked. You may want to create a method which checks if a player has won as shown:

```
private boolean playerWon(){
     r1 = tl + tm + tr;
     r2 = l + m + r;
     r3 = bl + bm + br;
     c1 = tl + l + bl;
     c2 = tm + m + bm;
     c3 = tr + r + br;
     d1 = tl + m + br;
     d2 = tr + m + bl;


     return ((r1.equals("XXX") || r2.equals("XXX") || r3.equals("XXX") || 
              c1.equals("XXX") || c2.equals("XXX") || c3.equals("XXX") || 
              d1.equals("XXX") || d2.equals("XXX") ||

              r1.equals("OOO") || r2.equals("OOO") || r3.equals("OOO") || 
              c1.equals("OOO") || c2.equals("OOO") || c3.equals("OOO") || 
              d1.equals("OOO") || d2.equals("OOO")))
}
```

And then call this method just before the turns are switched. That is before `playerX = !playerX;`. You could do something like this

```
TopLeft.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            if (playerX == true) {
                TopLeft.setText("X");
                 tl = "X";

            } else {
                TopLeft.setText("O");
                 tl = "O";

            }

            if(playerWon()){
               if(playerX) System.out.println("Player X Wins");
               else System.out.println("Player O Wins");
            }

            playerX = !playerX;
            TopLeft.setDisable(true);
        }

});
```

Comment: Due to the vague nature of his question, I supposed his program was probably failing to find the right winning conditions

Comment: If the question is vague flag it. Don't guess answers. I don't see how yours solve his problem anyway.